# Pass generic enum to a function

Tags: c#, function, enums

In the function below I use the switch statement to determine the type of enum I need to loop through. Is there a way I can pass a generic type of enum to the function to avoid the switch statement? Or should I be using something other than an enum to do this?

```cs
public static void ShowGroupSub(List<BasicTriListWithSmartObject> panels, uint type,uint sub)
{
    foreach (BasicTriListWithSmartObject panel in panels)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case (uint)SubGroups.Control:
                foreach (uint index in Enum.GetValues(typeof(**ControlSubs**)))
                    panel.BooleanInput[index].BoolValue = false;
                panel.BooleanInput[sub].BoolValue = true;
                break;
            case (uint)SubGroups.Presets:
                foreach (uint index in Enum.GetValues(typeof(**PresetSubs**)))
                    panel.BooleanInput[index].BoolValue = false;
                panel.BooleanInput[sub].BoolValue = true;
                break;
            case (uint)SubGroups.VideoCall:
                foreach (uint index in Enum.GetValues(typeof(**VideoCallSubs**)))
                    panel.BooleanInput[index].BoolValue = false;
                panel.BooleanInput[sub].BoolValue = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}

public enum SubGroups : uint
{
    Control      = 1,
    Presets      = 2,
    VideoCall    = 3
}

public enum ControlSubs : uint
{
    Bluray = 60,
    PC = 61,
    Laptop = 62,
    AirMedia = 63,
    ClickShare = 64,
    CamControl = 65,
    DocCam = 66,
    CATV = 67,
}

public enum PresetSubs : uint
{
    Main = 60,
    Edit = 61
}

public enum VideoCallSubs : uint
{
    Contacts = 271,
    Keyboard = 272,
    Camera = 273,
    CallActive = 274,
    AddCallContacts = 275,
    AddCallKeyboard = 276
}
```

This works but seeing if there are better ways.

Comment: Define "better". Also, the fact it works makes it somehow off- topic for SO. Did you check code review se if it would fit there?

Comment: Often switching on enums can be avoided by using a OOP approach where derived classes implement each the functionality of one switch case. But it is difficult to give an answer without having more context information. Also, why is `type` a `uint` and not a `SubGroups`? If you cannot change this, why don't you switch on `(SubGroups)type` instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well if you are looking for a more generic solution. The below solution can be adopted.

You can make your code more generic by using a single enum type for all the subgroups and passing it as a generic type parameter to your function. You can then iterate through the values of that enum type without the need for a switch statement.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Example
{
    public static void ShowGroupSub<TSubGroup>(List<BasicTriListWithSmartObject> panels, uint sub) where TSubGroup : Enum
    {
        foreach (BasicTriListWithSmartObject panel in panels)
        {
            foreach (TSubGroup value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TSubGroup)))
            {
                uint index = Convert.ToUInt32(value);
                panel.BooleanInput[index].BoolValue = false;
            }

            panel.BooleanInput[sub].BoolValue = true;
        }
    }

    // Your enum for subgroups
    public enum SubGroups : uint
    {
        Control = 1,
        Presets = 2,
        VideoCall = 3
    }

    // Your enum for all sub-items
    public enum AllSubs : uint
    {
        Bluray = 60,
        PC = 61,
        Laptop = 62,
        AirMedia = 63,
        ClickShare = 64,
        CamControl = 65,
        DocCam = 66,
        CATV = 67,

        Main = 60,
        Edit = 61,

        Contacts = 271,
        Keyboard = 272,
        Camera = 273,
        CallActive = 274,
        AddCallContacts = 275,
        AddCallKeyboard = 276
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Call the function with the specific subgroup enum
        ShowGroupSub<AllSubs>(new List<BasicTriListWithSmartObject>(), 61);
    }

    // BasicTriListWithSmartObject class definition
    public class BasicTriListWithSmartObject
    {
        public BooleanInputWrapper[] BooleanInput { get; set; } = new BooleanInputWrapper[1000];
    }

    // BooleanInputWrapper class definition
    public class BooleanInputWrapper
    {
        public bool BoolValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In this example, the `ShowGroupSub` function takes a generic type parameter `TSubGroup`, which is constrained to be an `enum`. You can then call this function with your specific enum type, such as `AllSubs`. The function uses `Enum.GetValues` to iterate through all values of the provided enum type and sets the corresponding `BoolValue` to `false`. Finally, it sets the specified `BoolValue` to `true`. This way, you eliminate the need for a switch statement, and your code becomes more maintainable and extensible.

Answer (score 0):

Since `type` does not change, the enum values are always the same and can be determined before the loop. We can use a switch expression which is easier to write than a switch statement to get the enum type for which we want the values.

Most of the code in the switch cases is the same and needs not to be repeated.

```cs
public static void ShowGroupSub(List<BasicTriListWithSmartObject> panels, uint type, uint sub)
{
    Type enumType = (SubGroups)type switch {
        SubGroups.Control => typeof(ControlSubs),
        SubGroups.Presets => typeof(PresetSubs),
        SubGroups.VideoCall => typeof(VideoCallSubs),
        _ => throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown type {type}", nameof(type))
    };
    uint[] enumValues = (uint[])Enum.GetValues(enumType);
    foreach (BasicTriListWithSmartObject panel in panels) {
        foreach (uint index in enumValues) {
            panel.BooleanInput[index].BoolValue = false;
        }
        panel.BooleanInput[sub].BoolValue = true;
    }
}
```

Another approach is to use a dictionary to store the indexes:

```cs
private static readonly Dictionary<SubGroups, uint[]> _indexes = new() {
    { SubGroups.Control, (uint[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(ControlSubs)) },
    { SubGroups.Presets, (uint[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(PresetSubs)) },
    { SubGroups.VideoCall, (uint[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(VideoCallSubs)) } };

public static void ShowGroupSub(List<BasicTriListWithSmartObject> panels, uint type, uint sub)
{
    foreach (BasicTriListWithSmartObject panel in panels) {
        foreach (uint index in _indexes[(SubGroups)type]) {
            panel.BooleanInput[index].BoolValue = false;
        }
        panel.BooleanInput[sub].BoolValue = true;
    }
}
```

I also wonder why you are using `uint`. It seems that these enums would work without specifying a base type. It would default to `int`. The parameter `type` could be an `int` as well or even better, a `SubGroups`.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```cs
    public static void ShowGroupSub<T>(List<BasicTriListWithSmartObject> panels, T sub)
        where T : struct, Enum
    {
        foreach (BasicTriListWithSmartObject panel in panels)
        {
            foreach (uint index in Enum.GetValuesAsUnderlyingType<T>())
                panel.BooleanInput[index].BoolValue = false;
            panel.BooleanInput[Convert.ToUInt32(sub)].BoolValue = true;
        }
    }
```

well... but now we cannot constrain the value of `T` (it could be any enum type), that's a problem.

maybe it truly requires something other than an enum... but so verbose...

the source generator might help in this case but it also seems to be a bit complicated...